# systemd process not starting python service

Tags: python-3.x, systemctl

I am trying to start a django service in development mode on a aws linux box using systemctl . This is my script to start the service

```
[Unit]
Description=API service


[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/mnt/services/backendapi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /mnt/services/backendapi/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Restart=always
#StandardOutput=file:/var/log/api.log
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I performed following commands to start the service:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-18 backendapi]$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-18 backendapi]$ sudo systemctl restart api
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-18 backendapi]$ ps aux | grep python3
root     10971  3.0  4.2 261456 41956 ?        Ss   21:15   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/services/backendapi/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
root     10976  4.5  4.7 346768 47180 ?        S    21:15   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/services/backendapi/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
ec2-user 10981  0.0  0.0 119424   964 pts/0    S+   21:15   0:00 grep --color=auto python3
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-18 backendapi]$ curl "http://localhost:8000/apis/v1/account_1/insights"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
```

I am struggling to understand why the service is not starting and where can I check the logs.
I ran `journalctl -u api` and it shows that service has been started.

Edit: answer questions in comment

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-18 ~]$ systemctl status api
    ● api.service - API service
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/api.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-11-19 21:47:45 UTC; 4s ago
     Main PID: 11572 (python3)
       CGroup: /system.slice/api.service
               ├─11572 /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/services/backendapi/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
               └─11575 /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/services/backendapi/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    
    Nov 19 21:47:45 ip-172-31-33-18.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped API service.
    Nov 19 21:47:45 ip-172-31-33-18.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started API service.
    Nov 19 21:47:46 ip-172-31-33-18.us-east-2.compute.internal python3[11572]: Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

Comment: Add 'Type=simple'

Comment: What do you see with 'systemctl status api'?

Comment: added Type=simple , still same issue.
systemctl status api command shows the app to be in healthy state.

Comment: Did you have checked the local firewall? Do see the port being opened by netstat -tln?

Comment: i am able to successfully run the service using nohup or just a regular command.